# 6 images centered, but 3 next to each other

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive website, and I need to create a homepage with 6 images in 2 rows (3 images per row), these images slide underneath each other when you make the screen smaller.

An example of what I'm working on can be seen on: http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/

When you make the screen smaller, you see how the images slide underneath the ones one by one. But just before the image slides underneath the one next to it, there is a small gap to the right (because they are all aligned to the left).

The images are 330 px wide, the max-width of the page is 1000 px. When you make the page smaller then 990 px (lets say 980px), the image on the right slides underneath the rest. But that leaves a gap of between 320 px. Just to small for the image to show, but large enough to notice. If the two images to the left could be aligned in the center, it would fill in the gap a bit.

Full width:

```
[image] [image] [image]
[image] [image] [image]
```

Smaller

```
[image] [image]-small gap-
[image] [image]-small gap- 
[image] [image]-small gap-
```

Smallest

```
[image]-small gap-
[image]-small gap-
[image]-small gap-
[image]-small gap-
[image]-small gap-
[image]-small gap-
```

Is it possible to make it so that the images are always centered in the page, but still slide underneath each other when the screen is made smaller?

Example of how it can look like:

```
| [image] [image]      |
| [image] [image]      |
```

I would like it to like like this: (centering)

```
|   [image] [image]    |
|   [image] [image]    |
```

Or perhaps: (making it stretch a bit)

```
| [ image ] [ image ]  |
| [ image ] [ image ]  |
```

I tried display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;, but this puts every image underneath each other, even when the page is at max width.

If anybody can give me a working example of a way that makes the images shrink and grow to a certain size when resizing the window, that might also work. Please see the social media blocks lower on the homepage (I just don't know how they do that...)

The current code:

```
<a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/feesten-1.jpg" class="borderit"><img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/feesten-1.jpg" alt="feesten" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-931" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/feesten-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/feesten-1-300x200.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px"></a><a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/trouwen-1.jpg" class="borderit"><img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/trouwen-1.jpg" alt="trouwen" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-933" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/trouwen-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/trouwen-1-300x200.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px"></a><a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/catering-1.jpg" class="borderit"><img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/catering-1.jpg" alt="catering" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-929" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/catering-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/catering-1-300x200.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px"></a><a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/condoleance-1.jpg" class="borderit"><img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/condoleance-1.jpg" alt="condoleance" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-930" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/condoleance-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/condoleance-1-300x200.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px"></a><a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/zaalhuur-1.jpg" class="borderit"><img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/zaalhuur-1.jpg" alt="zaalhuur" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-934" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/zaalhuur-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/zaalhuur-1-300x200.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px"></a><a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/fotos-1.jpg" class="borderit"><img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/fotos-1.jpg" alt="fotos" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-932" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/fotos-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/fotos-1-300x200.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px"></a>
```

The CSS:

```
img.size-full, img.size-large {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
```

Comment: You can set `text-align:center` in the div that contains the images: `.entry-content{text-align:center}`

Comment: Are the images going to stay the same size when the screen resizes or are they going to be a percentage width?

Comment: At the moment they stay the same size, but if I know how to control their growth when resizing, that might work as well. I just don't really know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use media queries for this.  I have done an example below using `display:flex`.  You shouldn't need to add bootstrap - I see no need for a full library to achieve this

```css
.wrapper { display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap; }
.wrapper > a { display:block; width:33.333333%; text-align:center; }
.wrapper img { display:block; margin:auto; }


@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .wrapper > a { width:50%; }
}


@media (max-width: 660px) {
  .wrapper > a { width:100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/feesten-1.jpg" class="borderit">
  <img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/feesten-1.jpg" alt="feesten" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-931" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/feesten-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/feesten-1-300x200.jpg 300w"
  sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px">
</a>
<a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/trouwen-1.jpg" class="borderit">
  <img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/trouwen-1.jpg" alt="trouwen" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-933" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/trouwen-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/trouwen-1-300x200.jpg 300w"
  sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px">
</a>
<a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/catering-1.jpg" class="borderit">
  <img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/catering-1.jpg" alt="catering" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-929" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/catering-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/catering-1-300x200.jpg 300w"
  sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px">
</a>
<a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/condoleance-1.jpg" class="borderit">
  <img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/condoleance-1.jpg" alt="condoleance" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-930" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/condoleance-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/condoleance-1-300x200.jpg 300w"
  sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px">
</a>
<a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/zaalhuur-1.jpg" class="borderit">
  <img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/zaalhuur-1.jpg" alt="zaalhuur" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-934" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/zaalhuur-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/zaalhuur-1-300x200.jpg 300w"
  sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px">
</a>
<a href="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/fotos-1.jpg" class="borderit">
  <img src="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/fotos-1.jpg" alt="fotos" width="330" height="220" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-932" srcset="http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/fotos-1.jpg 330w, http://www.mijncreaties.com/opstal/files/2012/09/fotos-1-300x200.jpg 300w"
  sizes="(max-width: 330px) 100vw, 330px">
</a>
  </div>
```

If you want them to resize with the page - just remove the size attributes from the actual image and change the width to be a percentage (eg add `width:100%;` to `.wrapper img` in the above styles)

Comment: Seriously, this is perfect. Just a very little bit of fine tuning the styling for the images, but the effect this gives to the images is just what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you can use bootstrap framework for this purpose, otherwise you need media queries for responsive layout. here is the reference http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will have a read in this, I think it will be very helpfull in the future to understand this better. At the moment I used somebody elses solution, which suited my needs better.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Bootstrap. Bootstrap is the ultimate tool to make responsive designs. With their [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) you can create roosters fairly easy. Try to create the images as described in the link with a div with `col-md-4` class

Something like:

`<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">[image]</div
     <div class="col-md-4">[image]</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">[image]</div>
 </div`

If you are new to Bootstrap. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp) link to get you started. All you have to do is add the 3 lined under the Bootstrap CDN header and you are ready to go

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out, looks like it is something very good to learn anyway.

Comment: Yup totally is. It also creates a bunch of classes to create error or succes messages. Totally worth it to learn

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap grid system. It will make you easier to design for every screen size. (small (mobile) medium (tablets) and large (Monitors)). Use a container, then create create rows within and afterwards, use columns to place images within.

```
<div class = 'container'>
 <div class = 'row'>
  <div class='col-xx-xx'> 'Your images go here' </div>
</div>
```

The first xx indicates the screen size. Eg: lg, md, sm, xs. The second one indicates the column number.
Now whether you use container fluid or simple container, that depends on your styling.
Use Bootstrap documentation for reference. It's simple and easy to understand:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will have a read in this, I think it will be very helpfull in the future to understand this better. At the moment I used somebody elses solution, which suited my needs better.